# asp.net mvc client side validation using jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does asp.net mvc client side validation using jQuery only work with views

which use HTML Helpers to generate HTML controls? Does it work with standard HTML Controls?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use validation without turning to HtmlHelpers. See this article for details about how MVC works in the background with unobtrusive validation.

http://www.blinkingcaret.com/2016/03/23/manually-use-mvc-client-side-validation/

Though I think unless you have a very specific requirement, rather stick with Helpers, it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

1)Add Validation Property in model
2)In view add html control for show the validation

1)For Model

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is Required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is Required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

2)In View

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "error" })
```

3)Most Important (Add the following link in the View Page)

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery- 
    validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation- 
    unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```